# swapping upper and lower with ASCII values and incorporating numbers

Tags: python, ascii, swap, uppercase, lowercase

I want to swap upper and lower case letters with each other using ASCII values.  The swapping of the letters works but the numbers get dropped.  How can I use this same method without altering the numbers in the string.

```
# input the sentance
def get_sentence():
    sentence = input("Please input the sentence:")
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    sentence = ' '.join(reversed(words))
    return sentence

ans = ''


# swap the upper and lower case letters
def main():
    sentence = get_sentence()
    ans =''
    for s in sentence:
        if ord(s) >= 97 and ord(s) <= 122:
            ans = ans + chr(ord(s) - 32)
        elif ord(s) >= 65 and ord(s) <= 90 :
            ans = ans + chr(ord(s) + 32)
        elif ord(s) >= 60 and ord(s) <= 71:
            ans = chr(order(s))
        else :
            ans += ' '
   
    print(ans) 

#call main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is the last `elif` supposed to do? And why do you expect this do preserve numbers? You aren't even checking for them.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **`else:`** and **`ans += s`** so only ascii will change others remain same.

```
else :
  ans += s
```

Remove unwanted lines `elif ord(s) >= 60 and ord(s) <= 71:` and `ans = chr(order(s))`.

Full code:

```
def get_sentence():
    sentence = input("Please input the sentence:")
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    sentence = ' '.join(reversed(words))
    return sentence

ans = ''


# swap the upper and lower case letters
def main():
    sentence = get_sentence()
    ans =''
    for s in sentence:
        if ord(s) >= 97 and ord(s) <= 122:
            ans = ans + chr(ord(s) - 32)
        elif ord(s) >= 65 and ord(s) <= 90 :
            ans = ans + chr(ord(s) + 32)
        else :
            ans += s
   
    print(ans) 

#call main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code.

1. `ans = char(order(s))` will (a) error (it should be `ord`), and (b) reset the answer to just be that one character.
2. Even after fixing that, digits are characters 48-57; they would all be converted into spaces by this code. That third branch should be

```
else:
    ans += s
```

This will add the non-letter character to the end of the string, with no faffing about with `char` and `ord`.

Why did you pick 60-71 to be unchanged? That's `<=>?@ABCDEFG`.
(Did you maybe intend octal 60-71, which is digits, colon, and semicolon?)

Answer (score 0):

```
# input the sentance
def get_sentence():
    sentence = input("Please input the sentence:")
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    sentence = ' '.join(reversed(words))
    return sentence

ans = ''


# swap the upper and lower case letters
def main():
    sentence = get_sentence()
    ans =''
    for s in sentence:
        if ord(s) >= 97 and ord(s) <= 122:
            ans = ans + chr(ord(s) - 32)
        elif ord(s) >= 65 and ord(s) <= 90 :
            ans = ans + chr(ord(s) + 32)
        else:
            
            try: 
                ans = ans + str(int(s)) # Would throw ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
            except:
                ans += ' '
   
    print(ans) 

#call main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```